# Data Table not able to get item JSF

Tags: java, list, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am new for prime face. Please see my code below.

Test.xhtml

```
<h:dataTable  var="test" value="#{generalServiceBean.orderList}" >

             <h:column>

                <f:facet name="header">Order No</f:facet>


             </h:column>


            <h:column>

                <f:facet name="header">Order No</f:facet>

            <h:outputText value="#{test.orderNo}" />


             </h:column>




          </h:dataTable>
```

Testbean.java

```
    package my.com.mesiniaga.sphere.web;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.el.ELContext;
import javax.el.ExpressionFactory;
import javax.faces.application.Application;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

import my.com.mesiniaga.sphere.domain.GeneralEc;
import my.com.mesiniaga.sphere.domain.Groups;


import org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable;
import org.primefaces.component.message.Message;
import org.primefaces.component.outputlabel.OutputLabel;
import org.primefaces.component.selectbooleancheckbox.SelectBooleanCheckbox;
import org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.jsf.managedbean.RooJsfManagedBean;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.serializable.RooSerializable;
import java.io.Serializable; 
import java.math.BigDecimal;


@RooSerializable
@RooJsfManagedBean(entity = GeneralEc.class, beanName = "generalServiceBean")
public class GeneralServiceBean  implements Serializable  {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    private String title ="General Eligibility ";



    private static final ArrayList<Order> orderList = 
            new ArrayList<Order>(Arrays.asList(

            new Order("A0001", "Intel CPU", 
                    new BigDecimal("700.00"), 1),
            new Order("A0002", "Harddisk 10TB", 
                    new BigDecimal("500.00"), 2),
            new Order("A0003", "Dell Laptop", 
                    new BigDecimal("11600.00"), 8),
            new Order("A0004", "Samsung LCD", 
                    new BigDecimal("5200.00"), 3),
            new Order("A0005", "A4Tech Mouse", 
                    new BigDecimal("100.00"), 10)
        ));


    public ArrayList<Order> getOrderList() {
        return orderList;
    }




    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }






    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }




    public static class Order{

        String orderNo;
        String productName;
        BigDecimal price;
        int qty;
        boolean editable;

        public Order(String orderNo, String productName, BigDecimal price, int qty) {
            this.orderNo = orderNo;
            this.productName = productName;
            this.price = price;
            this.qty = qty;
        }

        //getter and setter methods
    }

















}
```

I need to get data from testbean.java. But I not able to show my data in datatable. Here is the error that I get

```
    javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'Order' not found on type my.com.mesiniaga.sphere.web.GeneralServiceBean$Order

viewId=/pages/generalEc.xhtml
location=D:\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.8.2.RELEASE\base-instance\wtpwebapps\CGC_Dev\pages\generalEc.xhtml
phaseId=RENDER_RESPONSE(6)

Caused by:
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException - Property 'orderNo' not found on type my.com.mesiniaga.sphere.web.GeneralServiceBean$Order
at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:237)
```

Any one got solution?

Comment: Is this your only xhtml file? If you search for ".order}" in your entire project does it return anything?

Comment: You do understand that Spring and JSF are not compatible without some 'extras', right?

Comment: yes. i am new for primeface.

Comment: Hi dratewka, actually the error is caused by <h:outputText value="#{test.orderNo}" /> . Because I remove already the error gone